# Unable to install Typescript on MacOS using npm

Tags: typescript, macos, npm

I have been trying to install Typescript globally on my Mac by using the following:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

and also:

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

But every time I try to check if it was correctly installed, I get the following error by using **tsc -v**:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:5970
    var textToKeyword = new ts.Map(ts.getEntries(textToKeywordObj));
                        ^

TypeError: Iterator value undefined is not an entry object
    at new Map (native)
    at ts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:5970:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:7892:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Can anyone offer any guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? You probably need to update it - see [issue #40166](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40166)

Comment: @RobC My version of npm was indeed a bit old, however, after updating it, I tried to install typescript again, and even though it seemed to render a different screen after installation altogether (as in it actually installed properly) When I try to check the tsc version, it gives me the same error as before

Comment: Maybe try clearing the [npm cache](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache), i.e. run `npm cache clean`

Comment: @RobC unfortunately after cache clearing, I have uninstalled and reinstalled Typescript and it gives the same error

Comment: So, which version of _node.js_ are you running, i.e. what does `node -v` print to your console?

Comment: @RobC at the moment is running 6.13.1

Comment: I suggest updating node.js to a newer version - issue #40166, _(that I provided a link to in my first comment)_, seems to imply that it's an issue with node.js version `6.x`

Comment: @RobC thanks for your patience and help. Updating Node.js to version 14.x has resolved the issue!